# seeking help regarding Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I am trying to form a regular expression for matching the strings below.

```
ABC_NACKS.*
ABC_ACKS.*
```

As per my understanding the regular should be :

```
ABC_[N*]ACKS.*
```

But surprisingly this is not working.

Please do kindly help me where am I going wrong. I have tried several times now. I need help.

Comment: take * out of character class ABC_[N]*ACKS.*   `http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/12`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a character class and also you need to escape `.` and `*` , so that it would represent a literal dot and `*`

```
ABC_N*ACKS\.\*
```

If it isn't contains a literal `.*`, you may use this,

```
ABC_N*ACKS.*
```

- `N*` Matches a literal `N` zero or more times.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean is `ABC_N*ACKS.*`, but that would allow any number of `N` characters after the underscore.

Maybe `ABC_N?ACKS.*` is closer to your actual intent (0 or 1 `N`).

---

Character classes (sub-expressions in square brackets) have their own semantics. Read about them: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html